# jQuery event to detect when element position changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I would like to know if there is a jQuery event that I can use to determine when a particular DIV's `top` property has changed.

For instance, I have invisible content above a DIV. When that content becomes visible, the DIV is shifted down. I would like to capture that event and then use the `offset()` function to get the X/Y coordinates.

Comment: @Sam Dutton - No. My solution was to rethink some of the page layout and structure.  Things were getting too complex.

Answer (score 8):

The easy answer is that there are no events in the DOM for detecting layout updates.

You have a couple options the way I see it:

1. Poll, nasty but it may work depending on your update frequency requirements.
2. Tap into whatever event causes the invisible DIV to change size and do whatever you need to do in that handler

---

I shall correct myself.

I took a look at the DOM and noticed the DOMAttrModified event and found this [JQuery Plug-In](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/478985.aspx) that you might be able to leverage to do what you want.

As the article mentions, it works great in IE and Firefox but seems to have problems in WebKit.

Comment: I don't think that the plugin linked to will work for the OP's case. As I understand it, the DOMAttrModified event only fires when an attribute is changed by a script, and not after a change like the OP refers to. However, the propertychange event will (I think) fire in both cases: http://help.dottoro.com/ljdchxcl.php

Comment: Note that Rick's solution also uses polling, which means you basically have a tradeoff between something looking smooth and not burning through the CPU needlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I thiiink you should be able to do:

```
$(document).ready( function (){
  $("#mydiv").bind("movestart", function (){ ...remember start position... });
  $("#mydiv").bind("moveend", function (){ ...calculate offsets etc... });
});
```

Comment: on another thought, this might not be possible for relatively positioned elements

Comment: What are these `movestart` and `moveend` events? https://plugins.jquery.com/event.move/ ? In that case, it seems these events are related to touch and mouse moves, not necessarily arbitrary element position changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#someId").resize(function () {

// your code

});
```

Comment: this does nothing.