# How can I call javascript function when DIV position is change?

Tags: jquery

I need to call javascript function when div position is changed.how can I achieve that event of changed div position ?.

any idea ?

Comment: Have you looked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355015/jquery-event-to-detect-when-element-position-changes

Comment: Can you post the code moving the div? This would be **very** helpful to answer correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the div position by using Drag n Drop. you can use onDrop function on DRAGGABLE DIV.

Comment: no,Div position is not change by drag n drop but it is change automatically.

Comment: automatically? are you updating your page using ajax or what? please explain it in detail so that one should be able to help you.

Comment: I am using SetTimeout function to move div and I want to call function to get that div position.

Comment: You utilize a function for your set SetTimeOut right? Just add the function which is supposed to be called after you change the x and y coordinates of the div. HTH

Answer (score -1):

By using the onclick function in the div