# Fire Animation when a div crosses particular position

Tags: html, jquery-animate, jquery

[image]
The above picture states my scenario. When user clicks a button, i'm moving a `div` from Location 'A' [100,100] to Location 'C' [100,500] using Jquery `Animate()` function, During that relocation, the `div` should have to cross Location 'B' [100,250]. At that time, when it crosses the Location B i need to fire another animation.

Related to this problem i had surfed a lot and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355015/jquery-event-to-detect-when-element-position-changes) link.But it dont have an accepted answer. Additionally, Jquery has an event called `Change` , But unfortunately it is compatible only with `form elements`. My question is, can we handle events like `postionChanged` or `offsetChanged` in jquery manually if that really doesn't exist.? or is there any feasible method available to achieve my need.?

Thanks..!

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Search for jquery animate step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.animate` takes an options argument that supports the following method (source)[http://api.jquery.com/animate/]

> step Type: Function( Number now, PlainObject fx ) A function to be
>   called after each step of the animation.

In your case the code would look something like:

```
$('div').animate({
  left: 500
}, {
  step: function(now, fx){
    if (parseInt(now, 10) === 250){
      // call your animation method here.
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Fantastic, By the way i found [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1856-Using-jQuery-s-Animate-Step-Callback-Function-To-Create-Custom-Animations.htm) link, which is also be helpful in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test the animation through each step and run a function to test for the position. This is from the API documentation and can be easily repurposed for your animation.

```
$('li').animate({
  opacity: .5,
  height: '50%'
},
{
  step: function(now, fx) {
    var data = fx.elem.id + ' ' + fx.prop + ': ' + now;
    $('body').append('<div>' + data + '</div>');
  }
});
```

I made a fiddle for it. http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewDavis/6g8aP/1/

Answer (score 1):

here is a working solution:
i also used the step-event

**HTML**

```
<div id="#wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
<button class="go">GO!</button>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.left, .right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.left {
  z-index: 1;
  left: 25px;
  background-color: red;
}
.right {
  right: 25px;
  background-color: green;
}

.dot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 72.5px;

  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 2.5px;

  background-color: blue;
}

button.go {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 25px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var $left = jQuery('.left');
var $right = jQuery('.right');
var $button = jQuery('button.go');
var $dot = jQuery('.dot');

var rightPos = $right.offset().left;
var dotPos = $dot.offset().left;
var thread = undefined;
var animationStarted = false;

$button.click(function() {
  $left.animate({
    'left': rightPos
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    specialEasing: {
      'left': 'easeOutQuad'
    },
    step: function(now, fx) {
      if (!animationStarted && now +$left.width() > dotPos) {
        if (thread) { clearTimeout(thread); }
        thread = setTimeout(function() {
          animation();
          animationStarted = true;
        }, 0);
      }
    },
    complete: function() {
      $(this).after('<div>Animation complete.</div>');
    }
  });
});

function animation() {
  $right.animate({
    'background-color': '#0000ff'
  }, {
    specialEasing: {
      'background-color': 'easeOutQuad'
    }
  });
};
```

Notice, that I used setTimeout inside the step-function to call the second animation in an other context. I'm not sure if it's good to run an *.animate()* call inside one running animation. To keep it smooth it's better to do it like this, i think. Does anyone knows it exactly?

The other point is the variable *animationStarted*. It just remembers if we called the second animation. That's the other thing to ensure not to call a complex animation inside the step-event of an other animation. With this way we surely call it just once.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/algorhythm/vHdHR/)